# What could be the reason for missing events in usage of ngFor?

Tags: angular, primeng

In my application I use a lightbox style component. I play around with PrimeNg and ran into a problem that click events don't be triggered or don't reach my event handler.

If I create the related links in the following way, then no events can be catched.

```
<a *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" 
    [href]="image.source" (click)="onImageClick($event,image,i,content)">
    <img [src]="image.thumbnail" [title]="image.title" [alt]="image.alt">
</a>
```

If I create the links without the loop, then the event handling works as expected.

```
<a [href]="images[0].source" (click)="onImageClick($event,images[0],0,content)">
    <img [src]="images[0].thumbnail" [title]="images[0].title" 
       [alt]="images[0].alt">
</a>
```

The example code is injected in another component with the ng-container tag. Without injection it seems to run without any problems.

Destination template ...

```
<!-- that's the injection in the dest template -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="selectedFeatureInfoTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

The function that pass the template to destination is defined like this:

```
// the template is passed by this attribute
featureInfoTemplate?: (feature: Feature) => any;
```

In source component the template to inject is defined like this

```
<ng-template #infoView>
        <sw-map-lightbox [images]="selectedFeatureImages">
        </sw-map-lightbox>
</ng-template>
```

... and the source template pass it to the destination in that way

```
 // declaration to the member that holds access to the
 // template fragment in source component
 @ViewChild('infoView')
 private infoViewTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
 ...
 // the attribute that contains the the template ...
 vl.featureInfoTemplate = (feature: Feature): any => {
    return this.infoViewTpl;
  };
 ...
```

Comment: I doubt this is related to `*ngFor` did you check if there are errors in the browser console with the `*ngFor` example?

Comment: No errors in browser

Comment: The code is from a template injection scenario

Comment: What is a template injection scenario?

Comment: Can we see the `onImageClick()` declaration in your component?

Comment: I'm going to update the question

Comment: @SrAxi onClick is in problem case never called and works without the ngFor ... so it seems not related (code is to complex to post :-/)